# Return a String from AsyncTask to use in another Activity?

Tags: arrays, string, api, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask class that makes an API call and parses the JSON into a string for me. I then want to use this string in the Activity class and place in a string array. How can I go about this ?

**fetchDataClass- Aysnc**

```
public class fetchDataClass extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    String result = ""; //json result
    String coinNamesParsed = "";//parsed attributes
    String coinNames = ""; //String for each coinName with each iteration of 
                           //loop

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //Background Thread i.e API request
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); 
           //read result in from the connection

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 

            String line = "";

            //Loop that reads all lines and represents them to as a string
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine(); //read line of json and 
                //assign to "line" if not null
                result = result + line;
            }

            //get the whole json object from the json file
            JSONObject myJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

            //target the "result" Array of objects(BTC,LTC,ETH) and map them 
            //to a JsonArray for parsing

            JSONArray myJsonArray = myJsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

            //Itterate through the array and get the attributes of each 
           // object

            for (int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                //for every object in the Array cast them and their 
                //attributes to another JSONobject

                JSONObject myJsonObject = (JSONObject) myJsonArray.get(i);

                //Single JSON object parsed each iteration and name 
                //attritbute is targeted

                coinNames = myJsonObject.opt("MarketName") + "\n";

                //add the parsed result to the string coinNamesParsed
                coinNamesParsed = coinNamesParsed + coinNames + "\n";
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    //Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //UI thread



    }
}
```

This is the first class where the data is fetched and parsed. Here is the Activity in which I wish to use the result from the AsyncTask

**SearchActivity **

```
public class searchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

// Declare Variables
public static String coinNamesParesed = "";
ListView list;
coinAdapter adapter;
SearchView editsearch;
String[] coinNameList;

ArrayList<Coin> arraylist = new ArrayList<Coin>();

    //ON CREATE
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        /*
        *
        *This is the string ARRAY i wish to contain the result of the 
        *AsyncTask
        *
        * */

        coinNameList = new String[]{String data from Async HERE };





        // Locate the ListView in content_search.xml
        list = findViewById(R.id.SearchResultList);

        for (int i = 0; i < coinNameList.length; i++) {
            Coin coinNames = new Coin(coinNameList[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an arraylist one by one
            arraylist.add(coinNames);
        }
        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new coinAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
        editsearch = findViewById(R.id.SearchBar);
        editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    //do something on text submit
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    //do something when the text changes
    String text = newText;
    adapter.filter(text);
    return false;
}
}
```

**coin Adapter class**

```
public class coinAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Coin> coinNamesList = null;
private ArrayList<Coin> arraylist;

public coinAdapter(Context context, List<Coin> coinNamesList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.coinNamesList = coinNamesList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Coin>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(coinNamesList);
}
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return coinNamesList.size();
}
@Override
public Coin getItem(int position) {
    return coinNamesList.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_search, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in content_Search.xml
        holder.name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.name.setText(coinNamesList.get(position).getCoinName());
    return view;
}
// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    coinNamesList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        coinNamesList.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (Coin wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getCoinName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
               coinNamesList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Thanks for your time in advance :)

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question with something that wasn't a question anymore. You can find [your modifications in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0f9598a6-f4a2-4aad-a251-3fe4e990a4e1/view-source) and publish them as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a listener to send your string result named "coinNamesParsed" back to origin activity, which execute asynctask named "fetchDataClass", then intent to searchActivity and also bring what you get at fetchDataClass.

searchActivity:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        list = findViewById(R.id.SearchResultList);
        editsearch = findViewById(R.id.SearchBar);

        ......
        FetchDateListener listener = new FetchDateListener();
        new fetchDataClass(listener).execute();
        ......

    }

    class FetchDateListener implements fetchDataClass.IFetchDateListener {
        @Override
        public void fetchDataResult(String coinNamesParsed) {
            // coinNamesParsed what you get from fetchDataClass
            ......
            coinNameList = new String[]{String data from Async HERE };

            for (int i = 0; i < coinNameList.length; i++) {
                Coin coinNames = new Coin(coinNameList[i]);
                // Binds all strings into an arraylist one by one
                arraylist.add(coinNames);
            }
            // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
            adapter = new coinAdapter(this, arraylist);

            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
            editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }
    }
```

***After edited sample code like this:***

fetchDataClass:

```
public class fetchDataClass extends  AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    interface IFetchDateListener {
        void fetchDataResult(ArrayList<String> coinNamesParsed);
    }

    String result = ""; //json result
    ArrayList<String> coinNamesParsed = new ArrayList<String>();//parsed attributes
    String coinNames = ""; //String for each coinName with each iteration of 
                           //loop

    IFetchDateListener listener;

    fetchDataClass(IFetchDateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    .......

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) { <-----this line

        .......

            for (int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                //for every object in the Array cast them and their 
                //attributes to another JSONobject

                JSONObject myJsonObject = (JSONObject) myJsonArray.get(i);

                //Single JSON object parsed each iteration and name 
                //attritbute is targeted

                coinNames = myJsonObject.opt("MarketName");

                //add the parsed result to the string coinNamesParsed
                coinNamesParsed.add(coinNames);
            }
            return coinNamesParsed;//<------- you don't return what you catch
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        //UI thread

        listener.fetchDataResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. When you say "origin activity" are you referring to the searchActivity or the MainActivity of the app ?

Comment: I say "OriginActivity" is which you execute the AsyncTask named "fetchDataClass", cause in your code I don't see any other activity name appear, so if you execute in MainActivity, the "OriginActivity" just mean "MainActivity".

Comment: The OriginActivity is the searchActiviy.  I want to use the resulted string from Asyntask in searchActivity

Comment: You can see what I updated. In short, you declare views in onCreate() and do AsyncTask. When AsyncTask finish, it will do onPostExecute() and use listener to catch resulted string. Listener return back to searchActivity, and then just set result into adapter and set the listview. I think this way can do what you want to do!

Comment: thanks for your time - this causes some errors as a result of my adapter class. Please see the edit

Comment: Hi David, I saw your edit, but I cannot be sure and cannot find the definite errors, can you post what errors you met?

Comment: Error:(65, 39) error: incompatible types: searchActivity.fetchDataListener cannot be converted to Context - this occurs in the searchActivity when casting ( adapter = new coinAdapter(this,arraylist); )

Comment: OK, it seems like IDE is confused about OnQueryTextListener and Context, because the params which request OnQueryTextListener or Context, you just put "this", can you try this : ( adapter = new coinAdapter(searchActivity.this,arraylist); ), and tell me what is change?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I get an exception error now when executing - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity cryptobud.searchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array. Essentially the app has a button, when pressed the aim is to make the API request and launch the searchActivity with the JSON data populated for the purpose of search and display. In this case im targeting the "name" of the coin which is the first attribute in the JSON object. It would seem the array is not populating :/

Comment: That seems like different problem, you should post as a new question, and post complete log and related source code.

Comment: Its not - if i can get the data (string) in searchActivity it will work. I just need to be able to populate the string array coinNamesList

Comment: Please tell me how to use the string from AsyncActivity in searchActivity

Comment: I see your update code you send out "NULL" in your fetchDataClass, even though you send not null parameter, but you use String[] to catch String from AsyncTask in searchActivity, that would be problem, so can you try what I update, and try to use ArrayList<String> to complete your job, I think that would be work normally.

Comment: What did you mean in relation to the return. I noticed you added a return in the at the bottom of Background AysncTask. Can you explain why ? I will also try ArrayList<String> and let you know if it works :)

Comment: When you get data in doInBackground, you need to return it. If not, when the code run after try/catch in doInBackground, there has any other return "null" at last, you would never get data for this AsyncTask.

Comment: but the doInBackground is Void. You cant return anything

Comment: Forgive for my carelessness, I should modify the return params in doInBackground, because I just modify at the part of class extends.Can you try what I last update?

Comment: sorry dude but i see no change can you double check. Thanks

Comment: Please see doInBackground that line, and tell me what happened after you try.

Comment: Does not work - i cant return a string as an arraylist

Comment: Of course not, please look my answer carefully, I declare "coinNamesParsed" to be ArrayList<String> in AsyncTask class. And this answer is what I suggest to do and solve the problem that you don't know how to return data from AsyncTask all just this. You can return what you want to do your job, no matter is ArrayList<String> or String or String Array.

Comment: I managed to get it working after I tweaked your suggestion slightly. Thank again for the help